# Finding an image on a map without EXIF Data

Tags: image-processing, comparison, gis, exif

I'm currently thinking of ideas for my final year dissertation project.
I'm in my last year of Computer Science, and have a number of ideas. What I'm trying to see now is that if I can attempt such a project.
What I'm planning to do is find out where an image is on a map, but I want to be able to find it, even if the EXIF data for the image doesn't contain a longitude/latitude.

i.e., I'm wondering is it possible to do so without using EXIF data.
Can I use API's to compare the image to other images on Google/Streetview/Twitter/Facebook/Instragram etc?

Has anyone got any experience in doing this?
Any advice or points of interest would be really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely possible, but difficult to do with accuracy and a high hit rate.   As far as I know there is no public API for this, so you'd need to build your own corpus of georeferenced images and matching algorithms to match your image against a set of georeferenced ones.

Check out the [IM2GPS](http://graphics.cs.cmu.edu/projects/im2gps/) project at Carnegie Mellon and the associated [Google Tech Talk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dgif39IKT9A&fmt=18), as [well as the paper describing the project](http://graphics.cs.cmu.edu/projects/im2gps/im2gps.pdf).  There are the references at the end of the paper for more reading.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've begun to see a pattern in what kind of comparison algorithms and designs to use, so that's a plus. The IM2GPS seems like a good read. Looked very informative when I skimmed through it.

Comment: You're welcome.   Don't forget to accept my answer if you think it is the best answer, although you are welcome to wait for a better response.

Comment: I eventually found a halfway point of completing this, and created a fully working system for my final year project which got me 78%.

I'll have a link for it soon for those interested in this area.

Answer (score 0):

For those interested in how I solved this.

I used Python and the Flickr api. I stripped the metadata/exif from the  searching image, and stored it. I then used this information store on the image to build a search query that flickr would search for, finding similar images.

This involved taking date and time to limit how many results I got back, and so forth.
I purposely made sure any images I wanted to search matches these requirements, along with having some suitable search tags, and an estimated location, specified by the user.

The images found were done using Flickr's api to make sure that any image found contained a gps address. Therefore, any suitable/similar images found would have a location that could be compared against the estimated location, provided by the user.

(This is a broken down, simple version of the process, without going too deep into how the algorithm works.)
Any images found are then put through a comparison process in OpenCV.

Naturally, the IM2GPS research paper was of great use to me for this.

Comment: Hi, I am interested in adding similar features on top of https://github.com/jmathai/elodie. Is your code opensource and available somewhere, by chance? Thanks!